# Setup HTTP proxy settings in Android command line tool

Tags: android, proxy

I need to run `android` command line tool behind a corporative HTTP proxy in `--no-ui` mode. When I run `android list sdk help`, I see these two options (among others):

```
--proxy-host: HTTP/HTTPS proxy host (overrides settings if defined)
--proxy-port: HTTP/HTTPS proxy port (overrides settings if defined)
```

Where can I define those proxy settings? In the user interface mode, I can go to `Tools -> Options`, but I need to do it without UI mode.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this problem? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your corporate proxy parameters in the command options. For instance:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --proxy-host proxy --proxy-port 8080
```

And it should work

Comment: There is any way to set this settings permanently without UI?